# Makefile error while making clean check and install libneo4j-client library

Tags: makefile, target, libneo4j-client

**Update:** It was my fault, since I do not have the library `libcypher-parser` installed I should have run `./configure --disable-tools`. It works perfectly now :-)

It may be a silly issue, but I have a problem while completing the installation of the C library neo4j-client.

Since I have ArchLinux on my laptop I downloaded the whole repository from https://github.com/cleishm/libneo4j-client and done the following operations:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
```

that completed without any error, leading to the generation of the file Makefile.in

Then I tried

```
$ make clean check
$ sudo make install
```

but the results are:

```
$ make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.
$ make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

I don't know why both targets are missing from the Makefile, but I'm stuck on this issue.
I tried to look inside Makefile.in, but there are so many targets that I don't know how to recognize the ones I need...

Please help me :-(

Thank you in advance for your time :-)

Comment: The `configure` script doesn't build `Makefile.in` (which is not the file that `make` reads): it should generate a `Makefile` (which is the file that `make` reads).  Do you have that file?  Note that in general when following build steps if any step fails you should stop there and get it to work before proceeding to the next step: so if `make clean check` doesn't work, you shouldn't try to run `sudo make install` (this is _especially_ true if the next step uses `sudo` which could damage your system if it misbehaves).

Comment: My suspicion is that the `./configure` command failed and so it didn't generate the `Makefile` that the next step (`make clean check`) needed to run.  Did you see any error messages when you ran `configure`?

Comment: @MadScientist you are so right!! Thank you very much! I made a mess :')
I thought I checked the output of the `./configure` command, but apparently I didn't... I updated the question adding how to solve it, just in case someone as clumsy as me finds it useful.
Thanks for your help :-)